# Opencart Theme Designing without editing root files

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

I am working on Open Cart and i am unable to edit theme in open cart so that when i upgrade my open cart version to new open cart, my code remain stable. Even i have used VQmod and VQ manager for it but these give permission to work with cache and when i delete cache my code goes out.
I made my own theme folder and make it default theme using admin panel but one problem is that if i will upgrade my open cart version then modification will be done also in my theme which i don't want.
Please suggest me some ideas.

Comment: `i am unable to edit theme in open cart` - Which all files did you try to edit? Why you were unable to edit? `when i delete cache my code goes out` - which all files did you delete? `i will upgrade my open cart version`- how did you upgrade your open cart version? - Please update the question with all these details.

Comment: Dear Sir Thank you very much for your attention. Sir i am unable to work with xml file as all xml file create one cache file and i am looking that when i make a xml file and upload it, and when i clear all cache from admin panel using Module then my data file or cache file also goes clear. I tried Header.tpl in xml file. AND I heard that we can't edit our root files. That's why i want to work with VQmod but i think i am to learn about more and more about it.

Comment: "I tried Header.tpl in xml file. AND I heard that we can't edit our root files." - header.tpl a root file ? Can you please answer my questions?

Comment: Sir i know header.tpl is not a root file. But sir please tell in opencart if we change our models and controllers, at the time of upgrading opencart which files or folders changes.

Comment: 1. I was working to edit slider firstly with xml file.
2. I want to edit my model for this but how can i edit my model i don't know.
3. At the time of upgrading OPEN CART which files are there those can be updated i don't know 
@SankarV
But thank you first of all

Comment: So you tried to edit only xml files, right ?

Comment: I have changed default folder to a new name folder.
Now by using XML file i want to work or change functionality of models and controllers for my theme folder named as shopitout

Comment: `So you tried to edit only xml files, right ?` -  Can you please answer my question? Also update your question with everything you need to tell us. Your question lacks clarity. http://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/opencart-vqmod-tutorial/ - This may help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48873/discussion-between-hunger-of-php-and-sankar-v)

Comment: You've already accepted an answer for this question. What else needs
 to be discussed ?

Comment: Now there is another issue boss
i am feeling a problem i am sharing a code in chat. 
when i go to edit in controller using xml it replace always the search tag data.
whether i want to append the add data after search data even i have defined position too.
In chat i am sharing code

Answer (score 0):

```
Use This code its work.    
<file name="catalog/view/theme/shopitout/template/common/header.tpl" error="abort">
                <operation info="">
                    <search position="Replace" offset="" ><![CDATA[<img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" />]]></search>
                    <add><![CDATA[<img src="image/data/my_logo.png" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" />]]></add>
                </operation>


            </file>
```